# CSS :after used to show a image like not available

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I have this image [image: icon] and this is how I thought that I can put those two red and white lines to cut the camera icon. The problem is that I can't see any line in output. 
Where is the problem?

```css
.fa:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<p><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> Camera for not available</p>
```

Comment: Try adding display: block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the pseudo element.

```css
.fa {
  position: relative;
}
.fa:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
  top: 45%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> Camera for not available</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `position:relative/absolute`, `relative` in `.fa-camera` (parent) , and `absolute` in `::after`

```css
.fa-camera {
  position: relative
}
.fa-camera::after {
  content: '';
  width: 17px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<p><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> Camera for not available</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you didn't `display` or `position` the line. The other solutions so far haven't gotten the white line to work - you can do that reliably with `border`:

```css
.fa {
    position: relative;
}
.fa:after {
    content: '';
    width: 20px; /* made this a little bigger */
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff; /* border instead of box-shadow */
  
    /* added these */
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px; /* you'll prob need to tweak this */
    top: 6px; /* you'll prob need to tweak this */
    opacity: .8; /* can't quite tell, but it looks like you wanted it to be slightly transparent? */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

An in-browser inspector is a great way to figure out what's going on in situations like this. Here's what your version looks like in the Chrome inspector. The `.fa:after` has no width!

[image]

and here it is when you add in the `position: absolute`: it takes the dimensions you wanted

[image]

Then just add in position values (e.g. `left` and `top`) to position it where you want it

Comment: Yep, I said "so far." We must have been writing at the same time.